# How to migrate redis cluster without down time

Tags: redis, migration, cluster-computing

We have two different running redis clusters and we want to migrate one to another. Both of them are serving and down time is not allowed.

Is there a recommended solution for the migration of redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically just make one instance the slave of the other temporarily, and it will migrate all data for you. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/redis-db/KOhA-TD1V6U

Or if you are wanting to just move some keys, the migrate/move command will allow you to move values per key, which you could iterate over to move many.

Comment: Thanks. Another question, can we use twemproxy as the slave of the redis instance?

Comment: I am not super familiar with twemproxy, but based on the supported command list, no. It lacks move, migrate, and slave of command support. https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/blob/master/notes/redis.md

Comment: Thanks and we're finding the way to migrate one redis instance to a serving cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [redis-shake](https://github.com/tair-opensource/RedisShake/tree/v3) which allows non-blocking incremental syncing.

You can easily configure it to sync from cluster-to-cluster, standalone-to-cluster, and so on.

Configure the source and target in the [sync.toml](https://github.com/tair-opensource/RedisShake/blob/v3/sync.toml#L3-L19):

Then run:

```
./bin/redis-shake sync.toml
```